# Unexpected overwriting CVS/SVN repository files in Mac Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, svn, repository, cvs

I worked with Windows Eclipse CVS and CVS did not allow me to overwrite the latest revisions – I needed to update first.  At the same time one developer working on Mac constantly overwrote my files. We looked at this problem and found that his CVS Eclipse plugin allows overwriting the latest revisions without any warning.

Now I work with Mac myself using SVN Eclipse plugin and I accidentally overwrote the latest revisions from my co developer.  How to prevent this overwriting?  If this overwriting happens what is the graceful way of reverting to the previous revisions and committing them back to the repository?

Answer (score 1):

Wait? Something is not right here...

CVS and Subversion will never let you *overwrite* someone else's changes. The whole purpose of version control is to allow multiple people to work on the same files at the same time.

There are two ways version control systems do this:

- **Checkout and Lock**: The oldest systems used a checkout and lock system. That is, you checkout the code for changes, and no one else was allowed to checkout and make changes until you checked in your changes. The problem is that someone could checkout files for a week and forget to check them back in, or go on vacation. Then, everyone else is stuck unable to work.
- **Checkout, and first person who commits wins**: In this system, two people can checkout the same file and do their work. However, the first person who finishes their changes and commits *wins*. The other person must do an update which will incorporate the first person's changes into their working copy before they can commit their changes. This is what Subversion and CVS do.

So, how in the world are you *losing* your changes? Or, how are you *overwriting* the other person's changes?

Sometimes this happens if you are sharing your checked out working copy with other people. This is wrong and should never be done. Instead, each user should have their own separate independent copy of the project (Heck, you can even have multiple version if you want). When your partner checks in their changes, it shouldn't affect your files.

What will happen is that when you try to commit your changes, you will be told that your working copy is out of date. You'll have to update your working copy and that will incorporate your partner's changes into your working copy. You should then verify that everything is okay, and then commit your working copy which will now include both your and your partner changes.

Does this answer your question? Are you sharing all sharing the same directory, or do you have your own working copy? Is there something else going on?

Comment: I understand that "The other person must do an update which will incorporate the first person's changes into their working copy before they can commit their changes." But that is my question, why Mac Eclipse allowed me and other developers do this overwriting?

Comment: I use Mac OS X Eclipse and don't have this issue. Are you using a plugin like Subversive or Subclipse? Are you using SVNKit or Javahl? I use Subversive and SVNKit and don't have this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't figure out what the problem would be. I use the same two plugns, and don't have this issue. In fact, the server should reject the transaction that is not current -- it's not a client issue. Are you using the `file://` protocol? Is it possible that you're doing an update and manually undoing the changes? Have you tried updating your plugins?